# javascript speechSynthesis no sound

Tags: javascript, node.js, speech-synthesis

I working with the speech to text service of speechSynthesis in chrome.
It worked like charm until 2minutes ago, everything works but no sound!

this is my code:

```
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
msg.volume = options.volume;
msg.rate = options.rate;
msg.pitch = options.Pitch;
msg.lang = options.lang;
msg.text = options.text;
window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
```

is there a call limit or something?

Comment: According to the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisUtterance) `Pitch` is all lower case.

Comment: yes i know msg.pitch no msg.Pitch. also it worked before.

Comment: Suddenly it worked again, and i didn't change anything! i need to know why :\

Answer (score 8):

In my experience the Chrome queue sometimes gets 'stuck' and it's useful to have a cancel command handy. Next time this happens try running this in the console:

```
window.speechSynthesis.cancel();
```

Alternatively attach the command to a Cancel button. NB it can be on any page, not necessarily the same page as your utterance.