# Why the following JavaScript's Web Speech API not working?

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

When I click on the `Speak` button, the app is supposed to start reading the text in the paragraph. But nothing happens. For a test, I have added an `alert("Test")`; at the beginning of the `textToSpeech()` function, and the alert popups correctly that means click event does trigger, but the rest of its code is not working properly. **Question**: What I may be missing here, and how can we fix it?

**UPDATE**:

1. I am using `Edge` browser on `Windows10`
2. After making some changes described in item 3 below, it works on Google Chrome.
3. I should add `Resume` button for toggling between `Pause` and `Resume`
4. On `MS Edge` browser, I still have some issues described below.
5. I was able to make some improvements as follows: One issue I discovered is that I had to move the `<script>` tag to just before the end of the `</body>`. The other issue, I discovered is that I had to qualify `speechSynthesis.speak(speech);` with `window.`. For example: `window.speechSynthesis.speak(speech);`. Same for pause and cancel methods. But, on MS Edge browser, the app as a whole still does not work well. For example, you can pause when the speech starts, but when you click on `Speak` again, the voice is distorted. You have to refresh your browser to get the real voice (instead of distorted one) back.

**HTML File**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
</head>
<body>

    <h1>The script element</h1>

    <input type="button" id="speakBtn" value="Speak">
    <input type="button" id="pauseBtn" value="Pause">
    <input type="button" id="cancelBtn" value="Cancel">
    <p id="textID">
        SQL Managed Instance gives you an instance of SQL Server but removes much of the overhead of managing a virtual machine.
    </p>
    <script>
        function textToSpeech() {
            //alert("Test"); //for test only.
            const speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
            let voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
            let convert = document.getElementById("textID").innerHTML;

            speech.text = convert;

            speech.volume = 1;
            speech.rate = 1;
            speech.pitch = 1;

            speech.voice = voices[1];

            speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
        }


        function pause() {
            window.speechSynthesis.pause();
        }


        function stop() {
            window.speechSynthesis.cancel();
        }

        speakBtn.addEventListener('click', textToSpeech);
        pauseBtn.addEventListener('click', pause);
        cancelBtn.addEventListener('click', stop);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Apart from in Safari, voices are loaded async so setting the utterance voice to voices[1] may be setting it to something that doesn't exist. Try without that line, without the volume rate and pitch lines and after hitting the stop button.

Comment: @Frazer Trying without the volume rate and pitch lines did not make a difference either. But after hitting the stop button does make it work a bit better.

Comment: it's from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41247184/javascript-speechsynthesis-no-sound/44176574#44176574

Comment: @Frazer Agreed. Your referenced answer seems to indicate (to me at least) there is an issue/bug in Web Speech API. Sometimes, you have to hit the stop button (for cancel) to make it working again.